# How to explicitly refer to the global package?

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces

```
package Test
{
    public class TraceTest
    {
        public function TraceTest()
        {
            trace("Hello, world!");
        }

        public function trace(s:String):void
        {
            // Something else
        }
    }
}
```

How can I refer to the global trace method in the constructor, and not TraceTest's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your `trace()` in a different namespace you'll be able to access the inbuilt trace via its namespace (`public`):

```
public::trace("string");
```

Otherwise I don't think you can refer back to it.

Demo:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Base extends Sprite
    {
        private var _assigned:String;

        public function Base()
        {
            trace("This will be assigned to _assigned.");

            public::trace(_assigned);
        }

        internal function trace(st:String):void
        {
            _assigned = st;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an explicit way to refer to the global package but you can accomplish what is in your sample code like this:

```
package Test
{
    public class TraceTest
    {
        protected static var globalTrace:Function = trace;

        public function TraceTest()
        {
            TraceTest.globalTrace("Hello, world!");
        }

        public function trace(s:String):void
        {
        TraceTest.globalTrace(s);
        }
    }
}
```